# PHP Sessions Shopping Cart

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

Variables get added to a sessions array passed from another page

Details page here

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';

// cart code


if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_GET['id']);
```

Cart page here

Heres the output from some sample products

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(4) "3911" [1]=> string(4) "5005" [2]=> NULL [3]=> string(4) "3393" [4]=> string(3) "185" }
```

and the current SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM `wheels` WHERE `recid` LIKE (3911, 5005, , 3393, 185)
```

So I know the array is getting the values correctly (Bar the null)

```
session_start();

require_once 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/header.php';


var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);

$whereIn = implode(', ', $_SESSION['cart']);

// fetching products for cart
$cartQuery = "SELECT * FROM `wheels` WHERE `recid` = ($whereIn)";
$cartResult = mysqli_query($db, $cartQuery);


echo $cartQuery;
```

When trying to call the Sql result with

```
 <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartResult)) : ?>
```

I get an error

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in (blah blah directory) on line 121
```

What is best practice to filter the null value from the array? E.g. The array doesn't get passed the empty value, (occurs when they click the basket button).

Could someone explain why the while loop can't get a result, I'm ASSUMING it is because mysql query isn't returning a result to the result variable? If so what syntax should be used to pass the $_SESSION into the query to get mutliple results?

Sorry for so many questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `wheels` WHERE `recid` LIKE (3911, 5005, , 3393, 185)
```

you should remove empty node and use IN instead of like:

```
SELECT * FROM `wheels` WHERE `recid` IN(3911, 5005, 3393, 185)
```

Remove null elements:

```
$newArray =array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if($value != null)
        $newArray[] = $value;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: How can I remove the empty nodes?

Comment: you can Iterates over each value in the array and check if its value is null or not if it was null did not use that in your query

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL Query `"SELECT * FROM wheels WHERE recid = ($whereIn)"`, You have used `=` instead of `LIKE`. Please Check that. Also check once `$cartQuery` you echoed.